# CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrl - appearance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, cmfctoolbar

I try add CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrl to CMFCToolBar. I found ToolbarDateTimePicker sample. In my application I implemented CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrl the same like in the sample. The problem is that date picker looks otherwise than in sample's app.

Print Screens: http://fotoo.pl//out.php?i=961861_datepick.jpg

Does anybody know why the appearance of my app is different than sample?
Thank in advance!

Comment: Your image appears to show a problem with the theme you are using for the application.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how can I change this theme?

Comment: Theming is usually specified via a manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of problem is adding:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

to stdafx.cpp.

@rrirower, @user1793036 - thank you for your tips.